# Libgdx Freetype Font Generator Outline acting weird

Tags: android, libgdx, freetype

I'm using asset manager to generate my font using object 
FreeTypeFontGeneratorLoader, specifically I'm using this current parameter

```
FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontLoaderParameter();
parameter.fontFileName = "fonts/myFont.ttf";
parameter.fontParameters.size = size;
parameter.fontParameters.minFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
parameter.fontParameters.magFilter = Texture.TextureFilter.Linear;
if(withStroke) {
    parameter.fontParameters.borderStraight = true;
    parameter.fontParameters.borderColor = Color.BLACK;
    parameter.fontParameters.borderWidth = 1.5f;
}
parameter.fontParameters.color = Assets.fontColor;
```

(then I load my font in static variable in Assets class)

everything is normal if the app runs for the first time, 
here is the generated text with outline screenshot:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHTqp.jpg)

but after I close my app using this line

```
Gdx.app.exit();
```

and then open my app again, the outline is now starting to acting weird
here is the screenshot of weird generated font:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AInNU.jpg)

I'm already trying to dispose my asset manager in event dispose of ApplicationListener in Gdx, but sometime my font still acting weird.

if I clear my processing run in all task android, then the font is normal again.

Can you tell me possible solutions of why it is happening, and do you have any suggestions?
Thx

Comment: this looks like a shader problem, and might have to do with losing context to this shader. So as TomGrill Games suggest, this could be a static variable issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this problem happen because my app not closed completely because this line :

```
Gdx.app.exit();
```

is just doing this :

> Schedule an exit from the application. On android, this will cause a call to pause() and dispose() some time in the future, it will not immediately finish your application"

that's why I change my way to close my app using this line:

```
System.exit(0);
```

then my app is loading and generating new font when user open my app again.

Answer (score 0):

Android sometimes keeps static (final) variables even when the app lost its context.

When using static variables: make sure you dispose when required and set them to null afterwards. Or do not use static for assets.